# SPI communication between STM32F4 and Rasberry Pi produces garbage

Tags: stm32, raspberry-pi, spi, stm32f4

I trying to make an SPI communication between a RPi (as MASTER) and an STM32F410 (as SLAVE, on a Nucleo board). My PoC is simple, I send 8 bytes from the Rpi and print them out with the UART-over-USB on the Nucleo.
Here is the sending code (in Python) running on the Rasberry Pi:

```
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 8000000
to_send = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
#spi.writebytes(to_send)
spi.xfer(to_send)
```

and the receiving code on the STM32:

```
while(1) {
    memset(buf, 0, BRAIN_COM_BUF_SIZE);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi5, (uint8_t*)&buf, BRAIN_COM_BUF_SIZE, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    sprintf((char*) dbg_buffer, "[%d][%d][%d][%d][%d][%d][%d][%d]\r\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4], buf[5], buf[6], buf[7]);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, dbg_buffer, strlen((char const*) dbg_buffer), 1000);
}
```

and my SPI initialization code (generated by CubeMX):

```
/* SPI5 init function */
void MX_SPI5_Init(void)
{

  hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
  hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 15;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

Nothing fancy right? This is a one-to-one only communication but I set and configured the CS pin anyway.
My problem with this code is that it works like, IDK 5% of the time, at most. Rest of the time, I got garbage or even worse, looks like the HAL_SPI_Receive() function got absolutly nothing.

Exemple of current behavior:

I send:
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
and the STM32 receives:
[0][0][1][1][2][2][3][3]

Any clues and/or help to unlock me will be very useful, thanks!

Comment: You have to use the /CS pin even with only a single device, because it is key to framing.  Beyond that, your question is defective, because you say that it "produces garbage" but fail to provide any details about that garbage.  So we have no way to know if it consists of shifted bits in values, or non-ASCII characters more indicative of something like a buffer overflow in the STM32 program.

Comment: For example, if i'm sending:
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
i'm getting:
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]

Comment: Did you check the phase for both devices is configured ok?

Comment: yep, polarity low and phase 1 edge

Answer (score 4):

The `/CS` signal is required even with only a single peripheral, because it is key to accomplishing **word synchronization** between sender and receiver - the receive knows that the first clock after `/CS` goes low is the one that corresponds to the first bit of data in the word.  Because `SPI` is a `synchronous` interface typically without any minimum clock frequency, without synchronization the receiver will simply interpret the first clock it sees (at a time when it is looking for one) as the start of a word.

Alternate schemes where the start of a word is indicated by a *time gap* in clocking are possible, but they aren't really `SPI` and your code makes no attempt to implement such a thing.  Critically, if there is ever mis-coordination such as the sender transmitting again while the receiver is still busy generating serial output or recycling after a timed out receive attempt, it may well start receiving bits from the wrong clock cycle.

And even if you don't end up with the bits shifted in a word, you may still end up with words shifted in a message.

Finally, when doing binary-level communication between distinct systems using different languages, you must put care into making sure that they use compatible data encodings.  Python has functions for packing binary data objects in pretty much any element size and endianness combination you could desire, it would be good to use those to explicitly establish compatibility with the data type the STM32 will be interpreting the received information as.

Comment: It's presumably covered in just about any peripheral mode example.  Not yet personally had any need to use the STM32 SPI engine in other than master mode.

Comment: If that's now become your question, then you need to edit and make it the essence of the posted question.  If you want to do that, I'll delete this and let someone provide an answer to the revised question.  To an extent though, it's not really a question you should be asking until you have *at least tried* to find the answer yourself.  So how about looking into the SPI peripheral mode examples???

Comment: Ok, nvm, CS added. Nothing new under the sun with it.
When I send [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8] I get [0][0][1][1][2][2][3][3] ...

Comment: Does it now stop working entirely if you leave `/CS` enabled but disconnect it and tie high?  If not, you haven't really made things contingent on it.  It also seems like you should probably be checking a return value from the read function for success or how many bytes were received.  And the "doubling" is suspicious of some other sort of software problem as well.

Comment: When I tied the CS to high, the content is more garbage-ish (for ex. I now receive [128][0][0][64][2][0][0][6]). As for the return code of the read function, I get "HAL_OK", so everything is fine for it

Comment: If you are getting *anything at all* with /CS high, then either you have not actually enabled /CS on the receiver yet, or your code is *ignoring the failure to read* that would have to result from a peripheral SPI implementation dependent on /CS that never sees it.

Comment: On the STM32 (slave), I now have:
`hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;` and correspondant code in HAL_SPI_MspInit() generated by CubeMX. Is there something else I can do ?
Oh and I made a mistake earlier, with CS tied to HIGH on STM32(slave) I indeed read nothing. Looks like everything is fine on STM32, so... Python side ?

Comment: I made a scenario where I send a 16 bytes packet with 1,2,3...15,16 from an Arduino or an Raspberry Pi to the STM32F4 and check on it if the content is still correct (1,2,3..16). I get 16-17% of "correct" packets... 
I rather have something that doesn't works at all because this would means that I'm in the wrong direction. But here... It's working "a little", and I don't understand that... (and why ofc...)

Comment: I'd recommend you get rid of the while() loop and make this a one shot test after reset where you start the receiver before the transmitter, all to avoid any "end of one and start of the next" confusion.  Try using python struct's explicit binary packing so you know exactly what you are sending.  And consider getting a basic model digital scope or even just a cheap USB logic analyzer.  Also maybe backup to only sending a single byte and make sure you have 100% success.  Then make sure you can send two without ever misordering them, etc.

Comment: I just achieve a 100% packet reception with disabling the hardware NSS and using DMA (as I don't really need it, in a weird home-made "blocking mode"):

``HAL_StatusTypeDef ret = HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi5, (uint8_t*)&buf, BRAIN_COM_BUF_SIZE);

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi5) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY) {}``
Yes, this is kind of ugly/useless and but it works... Why ? That is a good question indeed...

Comment: That is probably only working because you start the experiment in a coordinated sequence, and not as something you can rely on.  Again, you must use the select line or implement a real time gap algorithm.

Comment: I understand that, but using the CS line produces garbage, I don't know what I am supposed to do here.

Comment: See one of the examples, as suggested days ago

Comment: examples ? where ?

Comment: From ST of course.  See their website.  Likely either in the download where you got the HAL libraries, or in another available adjacent to it.